# Add bounty events to revision history

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, bounties, revisions-list

Could timestamps of bounty activity be added to a question's revision history?  Or something that would show the bounty events for a question anyway?  Obviously the revision entries would need to be immune to rollbacks.  I think this would help to clear up some of the questions that get asked related to how bounties were or weren't awarded.

Or, could they even be added to the question page itself so that you didn't have to visit the revision to see it?  That might make more sense, especially for users who don't make it a habit to view the revision history.

**Edit:**
At the risk of asking too much, since it looks like this suggestion's going to happen :) (thanks!!)

Something else I just thought of is that it would be nice to also have a flag shown on answers that do not qualify for the bounty.  ie- Answers posted (and not edited) prior to the bounty being set get something visible indicating they don't currently qualify.  I know that's extra logic, so I'm happy with just the indication of bounty events.

Cheers guys!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This has now been implemented!

The question will now record who started the bounty, when, and how much was put out. It will then record which answer had the bounty awarded, and by who.

The answer will now record how much bounty was won, and by who it was awarded.

You can see examples of a [question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/67039/revisions) and an [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/67046/revisions). This is a retro-active effect, so all previous bounty questions will now have the events in the appropriate points of their lifetime.

Comment: Have you also considered [Timeline view doesn't show bounty award](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/58072)? Generally, is the timeline view something that’s still being improved (and possibly made more easily accessible) or rather just left as it is?

Answer (score 6):

Sounds like a pretty good idea - I agree that it could clear up a good deal of confusion about what happened to old bounty questions. I'd also like to add that "Bounty Awarded" and "Bounty Expired" events should be listed in the history as well.

Comment: Yes, that was my thought.  I would like to see any bounty event listed.