# accepted answer with bounty does not show up on the activity tab

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow, accepted-answer, recent-activity

One of my [SO answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2290148/nhibernate-pivot-table-and-or-getnextid/2348493#2348493) was accepted on a bounty question and got the bounty, but it does not show up in my account activity tab on my profile.

[recent activity tab on profile http://img194.imageshack.us/img194/9270/screenshot20100304at135.png](http://img194.imageshack.us/img194/9270/screenshot20100304at135.png)

It does appear in activity summary fom the envelope link. (also named recent activity).

[today summary via envelope link http://img682.imageshack.us/img682/3568/screenshot20100304at130.png](http://img682.imageshack.us/img682/3568/screenshot20100304at130.png)

Comment: Screenshots go a long way

Comment: This may be related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29262/add-bounty-events-to-revision-history

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Related to this issue -- I have changed the "Activity" tab on the user profile to only show accepts from *the current user*.

As balpha pointed out in his answer, that's what the Activity tab is supposed to do -- show the activities of this user, not of other users!

That was a 1.5 year oversight on our part, and it is now fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I have never understood why the "activity" tab on my profile, which is supposed to show *what I have been doing*, should show when one of my answers is accepted – which is something *someone else has been doing*.

So you're right, the acceptance doesn't show up in your activities tab. But I don't think that's wrong – I think it's wrong that the other acceptances *do* show up.

Comment: indeed, I agree, and I am about to change this..

Answer (score 0):

**[status-bydesign]**.

The "recent activity" section of the site is for *passive and indirect* events, such as what other people have been doing with your posts (votes on your questions and answers, accepting answers, bounties received, edits made, comments left), and badges received as a result of this activity.

If you want to see what *you* have been doing, go to the "Activity" area of your user profile. This is where you see the actual posts you have made, edits you made, comments you wrote, etc. (It should also list votes to close and delete, but alas this is not yet implemented.)