# "Answer accepted" is no longer part of the activity feed... alternative please!

Tags: feature-request, support, accepted-answer, recent-activity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [accepted answer with bounty does not show up on the activity tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41013/accepted-answer-with-bounty-does-not-show-up-on-the-activity-tab)

I'm used to looking in my "Activity" list (in my profile, not the notification area) when I notice my rep go up after hitting the cap, to see what was accepted when. It's always been very convenient.

As noted [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41013/accepted-answer-with-bounty-does-not-show-up-on-the-activity-tab/44111#44111), this was a "bug" which has now been fixed. However, it was a bug which was particularly useful. Please could we have an alternative? The reputation part of the notification area is harder to use, IMO - in particular because on a busy day, I'm likely to have had lots of (irrelevant) votes between accepted answers.

To be honest, some feed of *just* acceptances - and preferably *unacceptances* as well, to answer another feature request - would be very useful. I also think it would be nice to show this in the public profile; it's interesting to see what answers a user has had accepted.

Comment: see here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41013/accepted-answer-with-bounty-does-not-show-up-on-the-activity-tab/44111#44111

Comment: @balpha: Thanks. Will update the question. I wonder why it only showed up now...

Comment: Given that this is now tagged as a feature request for an alternative, I don't see how it's a duplicate...

Comment: the reputation summary probably works pretty well for most users on SO, though perhaps not for you.  You have to admit that you're a bit of an outlier.  I would like to see a hover over for the reputation display on the notification tabs show capped and uncapped rep separately, though.

Comment: I'd like to second the "unacceptances" as well - it'd be nice if we could be notified in some way if someone else's answer was accepted on a question we also submitted an answer to.

Answer (score 1):

Why doesn't `/recent` work for you?

The current design is much more logical -- the activity tab shows *your* activity not the activity of others -- so it is extremely unlikely to change.

Also, your accepted answers are already shown on your answers on your user page; just order your answers by "recent" and look for the tell-tale style..

Comment: I certainly accept that it's more logical the current way - it just ends up taking me longer to work out from /recent than it did from Activity. Does ordering by "recent" on the answers page order by when they were answered or when they were accepted? If a question from 6 months ago is accepted, will it end up at the top of the answers in "Recent" sort order? I wouldn't expect that, to be honest.

Comment: @jon the answer to some of this stuff, moving forward, will be "we have a beta API now, and clients should build to taste." It's really tough to have a one-size-fits-all website, and you are an outlier. But in a good way! :)

Comment: Yup, that makes a lot of sense. Looking forward to trying out the API when I get a little bit of time :)