# Bounty activity history anywhere?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, questions, bounties

I had a question with a bounty. I don't keep track of my reputation points and it seems the bounty points have been awarded and I am pretty sure the answer was accepted AFTER the bounty period expired. Is this how it works?

I am unable to track anything -- how many points I had before the bounty and how many after and when were the points awarded. Is this information available anywhere?

Comment: You should have lost the points as soon as you set the bounty, not after the bounty was awarded.

Comment: Please vote for this request: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29262/add-bounty-events-to-revision-history

Comment: So I lose the points regardless if answers are correct? Seems unfair.
Why am I obligated to select an answer if none actually answers my question?

Answer (score 4):

There is now a bounty tab on the user profile page which shows all current and historical bounty activity for that user.

Answer (score 2):

Bounty history can be tracked with the general reputation audit. Check out https://stackoverflow.com/reputation (or whichever site is appropriate), and check the day in question. You'll see a big positive number for the bounty, considerably larger than any other number as receiving a bounty is the only method to earn more than 15 points in one shot. Alternatively you can just skim for vote code "9", which is BountyClose.

Reviewing what mmyers points out, if you're looking for the reputation *lost* from a bounty (which will occur when you originally place the bounty, not when someone else gets rewarded), you'll just look for a similarly large negative number. The vote code for BountyStart is "8", you actually need this number if the bounty cost you 100 because it is possible to incur -100 for a post deleted as spam/offensive. I don't know the vote code for those, but it's definitely not 8!

Simply take the reputation from the day before, add up all the values up until the bounty, and you'll have the reputation before the bounty. Just add the number afterwards to get your reputation after the bounty.