# History/list of bounty questions opened by an individual user

Tags: discussion, status-completed, bounties, users, revisions-list

Thus far i have opened bounty for some questions... How can i view the history/list of questions that were offered bounty by me? I hope the question is clear....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Jeff's answer points out that there's a new bounty tab on the profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53414/history-list-of-bounty-questions-opened-by-an-individual-user/95887#95887). It's a lot more useful than the approaches from this ancient answer (one of which is no longer efficient or all that valid, so I've removed it), so direct your votes over there. ♪

---

If you are looking at your own bounties, then using the reputation audit as detailed [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53105/bounty-activity-history-anywhere/53106#53106) is the most efficient and accurate. Just look for all entries with a vote code of "8" in your reputation audit, the question IDs can then be used to find the specific questions.

Answer (score 6):

There is now a bounty tab on the user profile page which shows all current and historical bounty activity for that user.