# Please show active bounties on a user's global profile

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, bounties, network-profile, active-bounties

I would like a way to see a list of questions that I have a bounty on. Ideally, this should be on the global profile on https://stackexchange.com/. And it should be public, which would be a way to see if a particular other user has an active bounty.

Related but different:

- [History/list of bounty questions opened by an individual user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53414/history-list-of-bounty-questions-opened-by-an-individual-user) (I don't care about finished bounties, and I'm asking for it on the global profile)
- [track bounty questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55413/track-bounty-questions), [Could we please get some way of knowing that we've placed a bounty that's still out there?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55534/could-we-please-get-some-way-of-knowing-that-weve-placed-a-bounty-thats-still-o) (these are good too, but site-specific. I want a cross-site list.)

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55534/could-we-please-get-some-way-of-knowing-that-weve-placed-a-bounty-thats-still-o

Comment: @Lance: As you can see, I've seen that.

Comment: yep, I put that up there for everyone else.

Comment: this is basically completed (it now exists in your local profile); I don't see a lot of utility in having this pushed up to the network level

Comment: @Jeff My request is specifically for the global profile. I do want to have a list of my ongoing bounties on all sites in a single place.

Comment: I've a stacksnippet for that: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/298506/how-can-i-view-my-offered-bounties-across-se/298717#298717