# Include bounties in profile activity tab

Tags: feature-request, bounties, profile-page, recent-activity, network-profile

Recent bounty-related activities (adding, awarding, earning) are not included in any profile's recent activity tab. I can't think of any other standard activities that are omitted; even the relatively insignificant and impersonal activity of voting on a suggested edit is included. Bounties should be as well.

> [image]
>
> [image]

Comment: Is that a... *freehand rectangle* ?

Comment: Get in line! Close votes and delete votes were requested first! :P

Comment: @animuson True, and I've voted for both of those requests. :) Still, those are different in that they're moderation activities. Bounties are a more standard feature.

Comment: Oh yeah, and... **what's wrong with the "bounties" tab at the top?**

Comment: @TheEstablishment Why do we have *posts* here? What's wrong with the *Question* and *Answer* tabs at the top? The difference I see is that the *activity* tab is formatted to make the timeline clear, while the top-level tabs are formatted to focus on the details of the event. I don't think this information is less important for bounties than for posts. (Also, [the bounty tab doesn't exist in the global profile, but that's been raised previously](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94529/).)