# When are bounties considered as active?

Tags: support, profile-page, bounties, active-bounties

In [my user's profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/183484/martin?tab=topactivity), it says that I have three active bounties. (Here is a [snapshot from Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20210516075556/https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/183484/martin?tab=topactivity)).

[image: screenshot with bounties]

However, for two of those bounties, the grace period is over - so I wouldn't expect them to be among active bounties. (I haven't awarded bounty to any answer. One of those post has no answers. In the other case, there is an answer which was posted before I started the bounty - but I have decided not to award the bounty to that answer.) The following screenshot shows what I see on [one of them](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/363674) (and I'll include also a [snapshot from Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20210516075629/https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/363674/is-the-algorithm-which-reviews-questions-when-one-clicks-review-your-question)):

[image: Screenshot from a question]

**Question:** When are the bounties no longer shown among active bounties in the users' profile? Is it until they are either awarded or until the grace period ends? Is the delay in this case just caching and the bounties will be eventually removed from the active list?

**EDIT:** Coincidentally, almost immediately after I have posted this question, the number of active bounties changed from three to just one. (You can see the status at the time of posting in the Wayback Machine snapshots posted above.)

So caching seems like a natural guess. I'd guess that this question can now be safely deleted - but I'll wait a bit anyway, to see whether somebody has some additional comments on this, or whether something useful can be added.

Comment: Funny enough I ran my stacksnippet here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/298717/158100 and it showed 3 bounties for you and now indeed only shows one. Caching it must be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think this can be blamed on caching. Look at the timeline of that post you bountied:

[image]

The 'one hour ago' there shows a timestamp of 08:02:50Z on hover. So, the bounty ended minutes after you asked this question, since this question has a timestamp of 07:59:21Z. I think you were in a situation similar to the one animuson describes in [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/147577/369802):

> Easiest way to think about it: if the bounty notice is still present on the question, the system hasn't decided yet. When it does decide, it will remove the bounty notice.

Your notice was still present, so the bounty was still active. Once the system removed the bounty notice, the bounty also ended and was removed from your 'active bounties' section. So, bounties will stay in your active list until they are awarded, either by you or auto-awarded by the system, which doesn't run immediately after the end of the grace period.