# Can you award a bounty to yourself?

Tags: feature-request, support, bounties

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When can I not give a bounty to myself?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105033/when-can-i-not-give-a-bounty-to-myself)

I've looked through the FAQ but haven't found the answer.

If you answer your own question, and add a bounty on the question, can you award the bounty to yourself?

Or, if you add a bounty to someone else's question, and answer that question, can you win that bounty?

---

Update:  it seems you cannot.  If this is not already there, **can we add this to the FAQ?**

Comment: @Jeremy Banks: That's new! So basically it's up to the system to figure out who gets the bounty then...

Answer (score 6):

Once you offer a bounty, the rep is gone for good.

You can chose your own answer for a question you have offered a bounty for, but you can't reclaim the bounty rep.