# Can bounty be automatically awarded to my answer if I put on bounty

Tags: discussion, bounties

Refering to [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work). It says

> Can I award a bounty to my own answer? No

But can you still get half bounty points through automatic rewarding. It is not clear from the above answer. Does my answer count eligible for automatic rewarding. I am hoping yes but if not, why ?

Refering to BoltClocks comment to this [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113121/can-you-award-a-bounty-to-yourself).

```
So basically it's up to the system to figure out who gets the bounty then
```

Comment: One doesn't gain any rep if the offered bounty is awarded to one's own answer.

Comment: @devnull I know that. What about automatic awarding by system ?

Comment: No, it doesn't do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [FAQ answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/16067/221351), Automatic bounty awarding have few conditions to be met

> If the bounty starter accepted an answer during the bounty period,
>   that answer is awarded the bounty. Answers accepted before the bounty
>   period are not eligible to be awarded the bounty automatically.
>
> Otherwise, if there are eligible answers, the highest scoring is
>   awarded half the bounty amount. The criteria for an answer to be
>   eligible are:
>
> - The answer must have been given after the bounty was started
> - The answer must have a score of at least +2
> - **The answer must not have been written by the bounty starter**

The bounty starter can never be eligible for automatic bounty awarding. Once the bounty is given on the question the question takes its special place in featured section. Once awarded they are not refunded to bounty starter.