# Setting up a Bounty

Tags: discussion, bounties

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)

Is there a way to stop a bounty, for some instance that the owner who badly needs the answer had already found it?

Comment: It wouldn't be fair to someone who puts a lot of time into an answer trying to get the bounty.

Comment: it is not at all times that the answer fits enough with the question depending on the preferences of the one who asked..

Comment: If you have the answer you're looking for, consider posting it as an answer to the question - you can't receive your own bounty though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the answer is no:  From the [info page on bounties](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/set-bounties)

> Please note that once a bounty is started, the reputation is non-refundable
>   under any circumstances

Answer (score 2):

If you're speaking of your bounty question in SO: [Is there a way to restrict the external users to access my server files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13855696), the answer is **NO** everytime.

Once you slice off your rep. score, there's no other way to *regenerate* it. Exception - You could get some score by your posts. I think you've also read SO's [FAQ - bounty section](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#bounty).

> In any case, **you will always give up the amount of reputation specified in the bounty**, so if you start a bounty, be sure to follow up and award your bounty to the best answer!

If you know the answer to your question, feel free to post it as an answer (if it looks good), get the "self-learner" badge.. But, anyways - you can't get back your bounty.

Comment: [You can't award bounties to yourself](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116567/can-i-award-a-bounty-to-myself-if-i-provide-the-best-answer)