# Who should I give the bounty to if I figure out the answer myself?

Tags: support, bounties

I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21524977/pivot-control-showing-one-pivot-but-registering-taps-in-another) to which a user (romasz) replied saying he tried it and it worked fine. In comparing his code to mine, I figured out how to fix the issue, but not why the issue occurred.

The bounty was for "Looking for an answer drawing from credible and/or official sources.". I feel like I can't give it Romasz. His answer helped, me *reach* the answer, but was not the answer in itself. I also feel like I can't answer my own question since I still don't know what caused it.

I guess I just leave it open?

Comment: Entirely up to you, of course; but maybe whichever one might have been most helpful or got closest? Or just let the half-value, auto-award happen, if applicable.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I award a bounty to myself if I provide the best answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116567/can-i-award-a-bounty-to-myself-if-i-provide-the-best-answer)

Comment: just give it to Jon Skeet, "all your bounty are belong to Jon Skeet"

Comment: not really a dupe. I solved the issue, but still don't have an answer as to why it happened / why my changes made any difference

Comment: @ShadowWizard He's asking what to do with the bounty. The question you say is a duplicate of, asks if he can provide the bounty to yourself.