# I answered someone's question after I placed a bounty on the question. Can I claim the bounty?

Tags: support, bounties

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)

For this question:

[pip install requirement fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8352248/pip-install-requirement-fails/)

I offered a bounty to help encourage more responses, but when none were forthcoming, I took the time to research the issue myself and ended up providing a solution. The original poster accepted my answer, and no other suitable answers have been provided, thereby (seemingly) entitling me to the bounty, but I don't see an option to claim it. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

From [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work):

> **Can I award a bounty to my own answer?**
>
> No. This used to be possible, [but it has been disabled](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/97802). The user would not get the reputation back, and the bounty will be displayed as **+0**, “this answer has been awarded bounty worth 0 reputation”.