# Bounty didn't help

Tags: support, bounties

I've had the same issue of this SO question - [Eclipse 3.7.0 Indigo with CDT shows many false compilation errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7962655/eclipse-3-7-0-indigo-with-cdt-shows-many-false-compilation-errors/10738455#10738455) - and since it hadn't solution (the provided answers didn't solve the problem, nor to the question maker who didn't accept any answer, nor to me) I decided to start a bounty.

I realised that even with a bounty the question wouldn't receive much attention, since no other answers or comments were made.

During the bounty period I found the solution, and would like it to be accepted (not for the sake of the bounty but for the answer itself) what can I do?

Comment: There is absolutely nothing you can do to force an answer to be accepted. Bounty or not.

Comment: I've not looked at any of your other questions, but it seems the above summarizes as "I found the solution, and would like it to be accepted". If true, then the above title is horrible, and all other text is just noise?

Comment: @Arjan - more in general I wanted to point out that Bounties don't always allow you to give a question a great amount of attention. The fact that I solved the question (in my opinion) and didn't get attention for it is only a side effect.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot force the person who asked the question to accept your answer or any other answer. Even though you added a bounty, it is not your question and you do not have the ability to accept an answer.

*Generally*, good answers get upvotes (even when posted to old questions, because adding a new answer "bumps" up the question in the active questions list) from other community members. This is *especially* true of questions with bounties set, as more people are likely to be looking at that question and evaluating the answers it receives. And highly upvoted answers are automatically shown at the top of the list of answers; that's how the community "accepts" answers without being able to award a green checkmark. Unfortunately, I can't explain why no one has upvoted your answer yet. (Announcing it here on Meta will probably help.)

Comment: I understand, is there some other way (besides bounty) one can stimulate attention to a question?In the hope that users provide their solutions?thks anyway!

Comment: @Matteo No, not really. Editing the question, posting answers, and setting a bounty are [the recommended options](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-do-i-get-attention-for-old-unanswered-questions). You've already done at least two of those. There's no way to force people to look at something they're not interested in.

Comment: You were very clear, thanks for your prompt reply! ;)

Comment: "(even when posted to old questions, because adding a new answer "bumps" up the question in the active questions list)" Yes, for like 5 seconds.

Comment: @sepp2k There is no time limit.

Comment: (One can no longer [award bounties to oneself](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54998/i-just-awarded-myself-a-bounty/97802#97802). And I am sure that @sepp2k meant that the active question lists changes every 5 seconds.)

Comment: @Arjan Ugh. So in situations like this one, you're basically screwed. All he can do is wait for the bounty to age away and award it to no one.

Comment: Actually, in this *specific* situation I guess the OP's answer might not solve it for every one else. (I've used `-clean` a lot in Eclipse, but it does not solve all its problems.) So maybe in this specific case another possible solution comes in. But indeed, in general I guess expiry of the bounty is all that's possible without some moderator action.

Comment: @TheEstablishment - that's what I'll do, but it's a pity. In this case but more in general there should be a way to accept a clear and possibly problem solving answer.

Comment: But, @Matteo, as [accepting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) is for the original question owner: hoe would you know if your answer solved it for the question asker?

Comment: @Arjan - of course if you don't include correct libraries `-clean` option won't help ;)...but from when I use `-clean` all symbols get resolved correctly.

Comment: @Arjan - that was why I wanted some attention for the question. Probably the question maker doesn't even know I've answered. There should be maybe a `inbox message` delivered if someone puts a bounty on your question.

Comment: @Matteo The question asker would have received a notification when you posted your answer. Unfortunately, they haven't been on the site in a couple months and most users don't have email notifications enabled...

Comment: @JeremyBanks - yeah, but inbox notifications aren't very effective in my opinion. I lose a lot of them, (i.e. the ones coming from the comments)