# What happens if an OP doesn't get answers to his question with an open bounty and answers it himself?

Tags: discussion, bounties, expired-bounty

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)

I have gone through the following question that explains everything about the bounty.

[How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/16065/193055)

As [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/97802/193055) answer says the question owner can't award the bounty to his own question. That's fine.

---

I had six open bounties on some of my questions. I was frequently getting messages in my mail account something like the following.

> Please review the answers. If you feel one of them deserves your
>   bounty, award it by clicking the bounty icon to the left of the
>   answer. Otherwise, you might consider providing feedback in the form
>   of comments or edits. If you don't award your bounty, the highest
>   scored answer (with a minimum of 2 score) provided after your bounty
>   started may be automatically awarded half the bounty amount.

I had one question with an open bounty worth +100 reputation on StackOverflow.

[java.sql.SQLException: operation not allowed: streams type cannot be used in batching while inserting data into Oracle clob data type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12075253)

This question has no answers. I simply got the answer to this question as the first comment below the question indicates but didn't give the answer because the comment itself was sufficient to answer the question.

Just one question : As the last sentence in the quoted text implies, what would have happened, if I had answered my own question and had got at least two upvotes from other users? (with the only answer or the answer with the highest score) May it automatically be applied to my answer to my own question **what is implied by the quoted text above**?

The obvious answer should be **no**. Just wanted to clarify it once though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right. The answer is "no".

You can't receive your own bounty, either by manual or automatic awarding.

*As a side note, you should ask the commenter to repost their comment as an answer so you can accept it and mark the question as "solved". If they don't answer then feel free to self answer (making it community wiki if you don't want to benefit from any up-votes it might receive).*