# where is my bounty gone?

Tags: discussion, bounties, expired-bounty

I had assigned a bounty of `+50` to my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16984323/1577396) on SO. Later on many efforts I got solution and I posted it as answer to my bounty question. I know that one can't get bounty points on his own question. But my solution got more than 2 upvotes and I think it is eligible for bounty.

From [bounty description](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty)

> If you do not award your bounty within 7 days (plus the grace period), the highest voted answer created after the bounty started with at least 2 upvotes will be awarded half the bounty amount. If there's no answer meeting that criteria, the bounty is not awarded to anyone.

Comment: But you can't get your bounty back even if you posted an upvoted answer. That's how it is.

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards I do checked that question. I think they haven't given description for this type of occurence.

Comment: @juergend Then I think the discussion is closed.

Comment: That post specifically says: "The criteria for an answer to be eligible are: [...]The answer must not have been written by the bounty starter"

Comment: "I know that one can't get bounty points on his own question. But my solution got more than 2 upvotes and I think it is eligible for bounty."

Comment: @jmfsg yes I was just thinking that I might get bounty because it is the only solution and also a good one.

Comment: It would have been better if one get bounty on his own post when it is a good solution. Ya I understand the circumstances.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[As described here in detail](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work/16067#16067):

> #### Can I award a bounty to my own answer?
>
> No. This used to be possible, [but it has been
>   disabled](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/97802). The user would not
>   get the reputation back, and the bounty will be displayed as **+0**,
>   “this answer has been awarded bounty worth 0 reputation”.
>
> #### What happens if there's no answer after the bounty period?
>
> If after the end of the bounty period a question has no answers, no
>   bounty will be awarded and the question will no longer be featured.
>
> Bounties are best understood as exchanging reputation for higher
>   question visibility and increased answerer motivation.  A bounty does
>   **not** guarantee a response and is **not refunded** if none are received.

Answer (score 0):

Bounties cannot be [awarded to oneself](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54998/i-just-awarded-myself-a-bounty/97802#97802). Thats the way it is.