# A bounty being offered by another person on a question

Tags: support, bounties, faq-update-request

I have searched around, but cannot find the answer to this particular question.

If another person sets a bounty on a question. If the OP answers the question, can the bounty be awarded to the OP's answer.

It appears this is not in the faq or [here.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work) I suggest the faq are updated.

Comment: I am pretty sure that a bounty can be awarded to *any* answer, as long as it was not posted by the person who offered the bounty. (And even that [used to be possible](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54998/i-just-awarded-myself-a-bounty/97802#97802) a year or so ago.)

Comment: worth adding your question to the [how bounty system works](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work) with a clear explanation

Comment: @mehow yes I have gone through that post a lot,.. do you mean we should add this to that??

Comment: @CodyGray is it clear? I know we can't award ourselves bounties.. but I cannot find a clear answer to this...hm

Comment: @Skippy What feature are you requesting?  Updating the FAQ is not a feature.  In any case, I fail to see why this needs to be explicitly called out in the faq.  The faq tells you who can't be the recipient of a bounty (the bounty creator) and everyone else can receive one.  There's no reason the OP *shouldn't* be able to receive the bounty.

Comment: @Skippy Just propose an edit to the FAQ question. No need to make this a (rather confusing) feature request.

Comment: I've added this information to the [bounty FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work). I don't think it needs to go in the Help Center. It is admittedly a bit of an unusual question.

Comment: @CodyGray cheers.. someone just put a bounty on one of my unanswered questions (in cogsci), and I am thinking of answering it..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is YES, the bounty can be awarded to anyone but the person who raised it.

Nothing makes OP ineligible to receive the bounty as long as he is not the person who raised it.

The only restriction I can see provided in the [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work) and [help centre](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) is that *you can't award a bounty to yourself*.