# Reward bounty to the one asking the question when he found the answer himself

Tags: discussion, reputation, bounties

I have a question regarding [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21576449/how-to-dismiss-all-wpf-menus-etc-programmatically-to-get-around-windowsformsho).

The OP has put almost all his rep in a bounty on his question (stupid IMHO), and after a while, found out what the actual problem is without any answers.

If I read correctly, the bounty won't be rewarded to the one who asked the question, and is thus lost. Of course, he could create a second account, but that is against the rules as far as I know.

Is there a way for this user to get his reputation back?

Comment: [Awarding bounty to one's own answer has now been disabled](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/97802/216721).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, the user won't get the reputation back. Bounties are meant to draw attention to a question, not guarantee an answer. Attention was drawn, the OP got what was paid for.

It doesn't matter if the user later discovers the problem lay somewhere else. It could even be that the comments posted on his question after attention was drawn helped him come to that conclusion.