# Make it clear in the bounty dialog that it's not possible to reward your own answer

Tags: feature-request, bounties

When a user sets a bounty on a question, [the system doesn't allow them to reward their own answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/16067/773001):

> #### Can I award a bounty to my own answer?
>
> No. This used to be possible, [but it has been disabled](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/97802). The <kbd>+50</kbd> (or whatever bounty amount was allocated) award button simply won't show beside your own answers.

This is probably obvious to most of us, but I just stumbled about a post where the only answerer to the post placed a bounty on it... with the chosen reason being to reward an existing answer.

Now, there isn't anything necessarily wrong with the whole thing, but I fear that they did it **expecting to be able to reward their own answer**.

Here is the current bounty dialog:

[image: Image of the "Why are you starting this bounty?" dialog, with the "Reward existing answer" option selected.]

Could the dialog include something along the lines of *"you cannot reward your own answer"*?

Comment: Just in case anyone's curious, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70329826/13552470)'s the bountied post.

Comment: Note that both the accounts (the answerer's and the OP's) belong to the same person.

Comment: @Justin Hmm... never considered that.

Comment: I think this is the wrong place to say this. None of the options allow you to bounty your own answer but putting it on only one option gives the impression that the others do.

Comment: @Laurel You are so right! I edited my post to remove the specificity of that option.

Comment: @Justin what makes you think that Esraa Abdelmaksoud and Krunal Akbari are the same person? What do I miss here? The bounty wasn't even started by the OP, so no idea what's going on.

Comment: @ShadowTheGPTWizard See the question history. The bounty was offered by a now-deleted user who had an existing answer mod-deleted soon after the bounty ended. So they were trying to award to themself. (I'm not saying that was the asker. I suspect Justin said "OP" when they meant offerer.)

Comment: @philipxy not relevant then, thanks for clarifying. It is just abusing the system with a dirty sockpuppet account, they can vote and accept own posts as well. (I mean the example is not relevant to the question.)