# Can we add the number of bounties an answer has earned to the bounty award tooltip?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, bounties, tooltips

As researched [in this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51542/can-question-timeline-be-available-for-deleted-questions-for-10k-users/54888#54888), an answer that receives multiple bounties does have separate bounty votes in the system, but this is not visible to anyone on the Stack Overflow interface itself. The tooltip for the bounty reward states simply:

> This answer has been awarded bounty worth 150 reputation

However, the answer in question has two separate bounties, worth 100 and 50 each. I know that a method for [adding bounty events to revision history](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29262/add-bounty-events-to-revision-history) is planned, but this only helps the users who would check said revision history.

So I suggest that the tooltip for the bounty reward include the number of bounties that have been awarded. This will especially be helpful when we hit answers that receive over the maximum singular bounty amount, which would easily prompt questions on Meta about "How can this person earn 800 reputation from a bounty?" given how unclear the current tooltip is.

It doesn't even need to be fancy or anything. As well, the number of bounties is already known by the system to determine the total bounty shown in the current tooltip, so it's not like we need to do many new calculations. Something like the following would be quite sufficient without extreme effort:

> This answer has been awarded 2 bounties worth a total of 150 reputation.

Comment: I'm going to LOL when this is implemented as "This answer has been awarded 2 bounty worth a total of 150 reputation."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, Im doing this in conjunction to adding the names of the people who awarded the bounty.

Keep in mind that multi award bounties are an extreme edge case (we are talking one in 4000)

Comment: I personally see the name as being pretty low value. Outside from knowing who earned a bronze badge (which I've never really thought of as having even remote priority), what use is there in knowing who actually awarded the bounty? What action are we encouraging with this information? Is it really "way more important" than accuracy of information? I really don't mind the choice you've made and the declining, but the reasoning you've given doesn't really make sense to me.

Comment: If it's an edge case (okay, fine), why not do both?

Comment: @Jon @Grace Ok I'll do both, the main reason I want names there is so people can figure out who got the altruist badge.

Comment: Excellent. That sounds fair.

Comment: +1 because I'm upvoting every one of your posts I can find after last night's changes.