# Mention who awarded the bounty

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, bounties

Now that anyone can set a bounty on other peoples question, it might be nice to know who actually award it.

Comment: What do you mean exactly? "This question has an open bounty worth +100 reputation from Gnoupi ending in 6 days." is under the question I put a bounty on.

Comment: @Gnoupi sorry, you're right. I meant showing who awarded it, because afterwards the name of the bounty donor does not show up e.g. on hovering the bounty, see e.g. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183) which I guess was not awarded by the OP. (I stumbled upon this post because of [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56107/can-a-bounty-just-disappear-in-the-void)).

Comment: Yerp, adding the names to the tooltip.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Hover over the bounty award, it should show you who awarded the bounty.

Comment: Very nicely. I'm liking that an auto-awarded bounty is also immediately distinguishable (it's awarded by Community).

Comment: Did you consider doing a `GROUP BY` on the names? Mega edge case, I know. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51542/can-question-timeline-be-available-for-deleted-questions-for-10k-users/54888#54888

Answer (score 3):

I think the best location for names of bounty assignment would be as part of [revision history](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29262/add-bounty-events-to-revision-history). The only other reasonable place is in the tooltip. However, while separate bounties on one post are recorded separately, the tooltip will only show the combined total. See [the research by Jon and myself here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51542/can-question-timeline-be-available-for-deleted-questions-for-10k-users/54888#54888), and a related [feature request for improving the tooltip](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55632/can-we-add-the-number-of-bounties-an-answer-has-earned-to-the-bounty-award-toolti).

Adding names (which can be long, and numerous) will make the tooltip potentially unwieldy. Comparatively, attaching it to a revision history event, in which each individual bounty can be isolated, will look cleaner. Also, the name of whoever gave a bounty isn't something that's immediately necessary knowledge, so it doesn't hurt it as much to require a click to determine. There's no other reasonable location to place this information, so revision history seems best.

Comment: re potentially unwieldy, the odds of this getting out of controls are fairly low, I totally agree we need a history event for bounties, but I am not convinced showing the name of the person/s in the tooltip is going to cause too much visual clutter.

Comment: @waffles I don't think it'll cause too much clutter - it's definitely a viable and usable option and the edge cases where it'll break are ludicrously rare since they'd be a subset of multi-awards (themselves an edge case). All things considered, I just think the revision history is a better place. But as I mentioned back in my feature request, I'm fine with adding it to the tooltip - no reason we can't have two cakes and eat them both!

Comment: yerp both are done on dev, it will be deployed tomorrow :)