# Bounty winner tooltip does not check for duplicates

Tags: bug, bounties, tooltips

I stumbled across [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/152754/152859). 1000 is a big number so I hovered and saw this:

> [image]

Should be only one Pekka there.

For what it's worth, it's [waffles fault](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/56229/152859) but he left this bug to his successors. :)

Comment: Still think split personalities is a far more likely explanation.

Comment: What specific wording would you suggest if the answer was awarded three bounties? Two by Pekka and one by someone else?

Comment: @MartinSmith "This answer has been awarded 3 bounties worth 1500 reputation by Pekka 웃 and MartinSmith". I don't expect to have accurate count in the tooltip, for this I'll see the revisions page. But the current display is just... wrong.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - Your proposed replacement provides less information than the current text though. I'd rather keep it as is if that is the suggestion.

Comment: I actually like the current implementation. Whether call it a feature or a bug... it helps clear the confusion as to how can a single person award a bounty worth 1000 if the maximum limit is 500 (you know.. helps sometimes when our mind can't process things)...

Comment: @Aditya: Well, it does say “… has been awarded 2 bounties”.

Comment: @minitech: As I said helps sometimes when our mind can't process things ;-)

Comment: @Aditya I can compromise: "This answer has been awarded 3 bounties worth 1500 reputation by Pekka 웃 (2) and Aditya (1)" :)