# Why was the half bounty not awarded?

Tags: support, bounties, specific-question

There was a bounty on a question, but after completion of the bounty period, the half bounty was not awarded. The answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572449/convert-sql-query-for-different-database/3572493#3572493).

Why was the bounty not awarded?

Comment: "answer my question, but don't give me the correct answer, I know it already." Do you have a point, or are you saving it for later?

Comment: Any question that's tagged with every required tag should probably be auto-deleted; I don't think I've ever seen one that should be kept around

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the FAQ says, *"the highest voted answer **created after the bounty started** with at least 2 upvotes will be awarded half the bounty amount"*.
Your answer was created before the bounty was awarded, thus you couldn't receive the bounty automatically.

Comment: I am not so sure. First he says half the bounty was awarded, then he says none. I guess we are both right :) However looking at the question there is no bounty that was awarded.

Comment: @Diago: I don't see any deleted answers, no awarded bounties and no answers that would have been applicable anyway, so... :) Lets hope [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29262/add-bounty-events-to-revision-history) gets implemented at some point so clarifying such things would be easier.

Answer (score 2):

> dont post faq link i knew it already

Well then why are you asking? Seriously? From the FAQ *(That you already knew about)*:

> If you do not award your bounty within  7 days, the highest voted answer created after the bounty started with at least 2 upvotes will be awarded half the bounty amount.

I.e. The person that posted the bounty did not come back to award it, and the system did so automatically.

**The Good News** The bounty system works as designed.

**Update**

Georg correctly identified that there was no qualifying criteria to allocate the bounty, also I can't find any proof that there ever was a bounty on the question at all.

Comment: There was no bounty awarded automatically as there was no applicable answer.